# Android Search Bar

Tags: android, search, searchbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search bar widget in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121048/search-bar-widget-in-android)

I have to implement a "Search Bar" in my application.Please let me know how/where to start from as i'm a newbie to android.Code is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [**Creating a Search Interface**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).